# invalid Argument Error socket.curve_server = 1; when using nodejs addon for zeromq

Tags: node.js, zeromq

i am trying to use curve mechanism for encryption in zeromq using nodejs, but on step socket.curve_server = 1 i get invalid argument error, even this error occurs for socket.curve_serverkey = serverPublicKey;

Comment: Hi, ZMQ needs to be built and linked with libsodium or tweetnacl. On my side, my problem is that I don't know how to do that with npm... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238555/how-can-do-to-get-zeromq-js-properly-installed-with-libsodium-using-npm

Comment: Try using zmq-zap, it works for me, but i am having issues like not able to send and receive request.